# Canvas не Работает на Unity

Tags: unity3d, unity-canvas

Я пытаюсь создать элемент Canvas, а он не работает, почему?
Я просто новичок, я с такими проблемами сталкиваюсь впервые.
Я работаю на версии 2020.3.21f1.
Что нужно сделать для того чтобы была возможность это добавлять.
Я пробывал другие версии, там тоже самое.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Momds.png

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вы где работаете? Лучшая, по моему мнению,  2017 версия, нет проблем с Canvas.

Answer (score 2):

Правая кнопка мыши в иерархии(Hierarchy, там где все объекты сцены) -и выбираете в появившемся списке canvas. Вы уверены что делаете всё правильно?

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Вы не в той вкладке. Вам нужна вкладка GameObject -> UI -> Canvas.